# Can an eigenvector be normalized in multiple ways?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that an eigenvector of some matrix is given as follows:

$C\left (-\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{b^*}},1  \right )$

Where $b$ is a complex constant and $C$ is to be determined by normalization. I would expect a unique $C$ that normalizes the vector. Yet, somehow I found two:

$C_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $C_2=-\frac{\sqrt{b^*}}{\sqrt{b}\sqrt{2}}$

Which of these two constants is correct? For reasons unknown, the mark scheme of the exam allows for $C_1$ only.

Note that choosing $C_1$ over $C_2$ based on the fact that it is "simpler" is not acceptable, as it is simpler only in this specific example. I could have scaled the eigenvector above to make $C_2$ a simpler choice.

I am incredibly confused now. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots more than just two constants. If $v$ is a non-zero vector in $\Bbb{C}^n$, then if $\lambda=\frac{1}{\|v\|}e^{i\theta}$ we get
$$\|\lambda v\|=|\lambda|\|v\|=\frac{1}{\|v\|}\|v\|=1.$$
for any $\theta\in\Bbb{R}$. Therefore both $C_1$ and $C_2$ are correct, as can be seen by `computing' $|\sqrt{b^*/b}|=1$.